# Assertions during Django test case setUps

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm just learning the approaches for testing in Django using the built-in testing tools, particularly the `django.test.TestCase`. I'm wondering if it is best-practice to use assertion methods during the initial `setUp` of a new test class?

For example, I have the following models:

```
class TestProduct(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class TestPrimaryImage(BaseModel):
    url = models.TextField(...)
    product = models.ForeignKey('TestProduct', ...)
```

It's a product that will have a primary image specified by a `ForeignKey` relationship with a `TestPrimaryImage` class entry.

Following the examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/
I am creating a testing class as such:

```
class NewProductTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        models.TestProduct.objects.create(
            name='TestProductName'
        )

    def TestMainImage(self):

        models.TestPrimaryImage.objects.create(
            url="https://example.com/test-image-url.jpg",
            product=?
        )
```

The part that I'm not sure of centers about the `TestMainImage` method which requires a `TestProduct` class to reference. Is it appropriate to do the following during `setUp`:

```
def setUp(self):

    self.test_product = models.TestProduct.objects.create(
        name='TestProductName'
    )

    self.assertIsInstance(self.test_product, models.TestProduct)
```

Assigning the newly created object to a class variable and asserting its creation? The assertion would imply that if the new product isn't successfully created none of the other testing methods would be able to run at all. For example, `TestMainImage` would have no product to create a reference to during creation.

This *seems* like a sensible approach to me but I'm new to Django and not to be confused for a veteran of testing in general.

Comment: Why you have to add assertion in setUp? If the first setup is failed, it's natural that all related unit tests are failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always keep this this in  mind: **never write tests for django internals**

django is already well tested and if you think there is a need to test something send them a pull requst

so for your sample, as we know `models.TestProduct.objects.create()` always returns an instance or throws an execption. so you don't need to test anything

Comment: Ok, that makes complete sense. I guess my follow up to that would be if it's sensible to assign the initial `models.TestProduct.objects.create(...)` to a variable during `setUp` for later reference? Such as `self.test_product = models.TestProduct.objects.create(...)`

Comment: yeah, actually `setUp` is made to write these kind of codes :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seemed like the appropriate place but I was unsure.

Comment: note that I recommend using variables names without prefix `test_` which may cause confusion (using variable names prefixed with `test_` makes your code hard to read cause test methods already have to be prefixed with `test_`)